# Please explain the x86 assembly language instruction lds si,[bp+0] in the code below

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The first 7 lines of code in a FAT16 boot sector are shown below. The `lds` instruction is on the 7th line. I read the Intel reference about `lds`. My interpretation is: the location of the data byte at `[bp+0]` will be used to set the values of the `ds` and `si` registers. There just isn't enough information in the code below to do that. (Note `ds=0` and `si=0x80` in the MBR code that runs just before the code shown below is started.)

QUESTION: Please tell me what are the values of `ds` and `si` after the 7th line of code runs.

```
xor cx,cx
mov ss,cx
mov sp,0x7bfc
push ss
pop es  
mov bp,0x78
lds si,[bp+0x0]
```

Answer (score 3):

`xor` sets cx to zero. Then `ss` and `sp` are initialised to the far pointer 0:7BFCh. (It is important to set `sp` in the very next instruction after setting `ss`.) Then `es` is set to equal `ss`, that is zero. Then `bp` is set to 78h. 78h is 4 times 1Eh. That means the `lds si` loads a far pointer at `dword [0:78h]` into the `ds:si` register pair. 0:78h is where the interrupt vector for interrupt 1Eh lives. This happens to be [used as a pointer to a DPT](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/55/24.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of lds, I understand now. I had thought this was a FAT16 boot sector from a HDD formatted by DOS 6.22 but I now realize it was on a floppy disk. The file system field at byte 0x36 says FAT12,  I have several boot sectors from old PCs. I disassembled one from a HDD formatted with Ranish Partition Manager and went thru the code somewhat. It is quite different from this one.